# ASP MVC API response to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im using an api to obtain some financial information for clients in out system.

The information returned from the API is passed to a model(ReportResponse) and displayed in a view (Report)

within the view i look through the items in the Model using a foreach and display as follows

```
  @foreach (var r in Model.JsonReport.ReportDetail.FirstAddress.DataSections.AccountData.AccountDataDetail.AccountDataItem.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
    {
        if (Decimal.Parse(r.value.Balances.Current.ToString().Replace("£", "")) > 0)

        {



            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @r.value.AccountOverview.CompanyName

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="@r.i" onclick="SubmitDebt(@r.i)">Save</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Current Balance
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @r.value.Balances.Current
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Default Delinquent
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @r.value.Balances.DefaultDelinquent
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Start
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @r.value.Balances.Start
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Account Number
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @r.value.AccountOverview.AccountNumber
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Account Type
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @r.value.AccountOverview.AccountType
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Company Type
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @r.value.AccountOverview.CompanyType
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Credit Limit
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @r.value.AccountOverview.CreditLimit
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Credit Limit
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @r.value.AccountOverview.JointAccount
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        }

    }
```

the information is then reviewed with the client who will be on the phone, and if applicable i then want this information adding to our Debts model.

My question is how do i map objects from the Report view to a debt model?

As you can see i do not have a strongly typed view, and the amount information returned from the API is variable and therefore needs to be dynamic

I would ideally like to be able to add a button to each section of the report that allows the user to press save, at which point i want just that one section on the report to be placed in my debt model and stored in the database

Comment: U can simply generate view model form response n use that vm in ur razor

Comment: If I understand you correctly then this is not going to work. The view is not submitted when you click a button. A form POST only returns *fields*, like input, select. I do not see fields in your view. So you can return an id only, unless you add (hidden) fields.

Comment: Ruard van Elburg is correct. You need to wrap your view in a form, display the data in Textboxes or hidden controls for binding... and then post that form to a controller. You can then manipulate the posted model as you see fit.

Comment: does someone want to add this as an answer and i will mark appropriately. Thank for your help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work. The view is not submitted when you click a button. A form POST only returns fields, like input, select which are in the submitted form. I do not see a form, nor fields in your view. So you can return an id only.